# Como partir un fichero .csv por un campo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Resulta que tengo un fichero, en la que se guardar las encuestas y preguntas(columnas) por ejemplo:

```
opinion|date    |¿Tienes coche?|Color coche|¿Tienes móvil?|Tipo_contrato|Seguro hogar
Coches |28/08/18|    Si        |Rojo       |              |               |
Movil  |28/08/18|              |           |Si            |Fijo           |
Hogar  |28/08/18|              |           |              |               |No
```

Y quiero particionar el fichero según el tipo de opinión y descartar las demás columnas, por ejemplo que si lo parto por **Coche**, me cree un fichero con las preguntas de esa encuesta

```
opinion|date    |¿Tienes coche?|Color coche|
Coches |28/08/18|    Si        |Rojo       |
```

Estaba haciendo este proceso con python, utilizando pandas.

¿Como puedo hacer este proceso?

Comment: Una pregunta, es completamente necesario que esto lo haga Python ??? No lo podrías hacer en Excel ????

Comment: con Excel te refieres a mano, es decir, filtrando la opinión y mirando que campos de respuestas se rellenan y luego copiar y pegar en otro excel? Lo quería hacer a código para automatizarlo ya que el ejemplo que te puse no es como el que tengo que trabajar en realidad

Comment: Ya ha sido  contestado algo similar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96541/filtrar-datos-al-cargar-csv-usando-pandas-en-python-3-x o podrías usar importante Cvs aquí abordan ese tema https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-read-and-write-csv-files-in-python--cms-29907

Answer (score 1):

Creo que he conseguido lo que quería hacer, por si alguien le sirve:

1 Leo el fichero en bruto y lo guardo filtrado por la columna que necesito pero que todavia contiene columnas vacias

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

leerDatos = pd.read_csv('opiniones.csv', sep = ';',encoding='utf-8')
leerDatos = leerDatos.replace('',np.nan)
#leerDatos = leerDatos.dropna(axis ="columns", how ="any")
datos = pd.DataFrame(leerDatos)
#En datos2 elijo la columna por la que quiero partir el fichero
datos2 = datos[datos['opinion']== 'coche']    
#Guardo el fichero por ejemplo en .csv
datos2.to_csv('fichero_opinion_filtrado.csv')
```

2 Leo el fichero filtrado con columnas sobrantes(columnas vacias) y las quito

```
leerDatosFiltrados = pd.read_csv('fichero_opinion_filtrado.csv', sep = ',', encoding = 'utf-8')
datosFiltrados = pd.DataFrame(leerDatosFiltrados)
datosFiltrados = datosFiltrados.replace('',np.nan)
datosFiltrados = datosFiltrados.dropna(axis="columns", how="any")
datosFiltrados.to_csv('fichero_final_1.csv')
```

Así eliminare columnas vacías y obtendría por cada opinión, las columnas necesarias